# Horizontal Alignment within selected cells

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, tabularx, arrays

I'm dealing with the following table:

```
   \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{array} 
    \usepackage{booktabs}


\begin{document}   

 \begin{table}[htbp]
        \caption{Test Cases} % title of Table
        \centering % used for centering table
        \addtolength{\leftskip} {-2cm}
        \addtolength{\rightskip}{-2cm}
        \begin{tabular}{l l c c c | c >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.5cm}} % columns type and number    
        \hline\hline %inserts double horizontal lines
        Parameters & &NoCross\#1 & NoCross\#2 & NoCross\#3 & Cross\#1 & Cross\#2 \\ [0.5ex] % inserts table
        %heading
        \hline % inserts single horizontal line
        mass &[kg]               & 1500     & 1500      &1500           & 1500        &1500\\ % inserting body of the table                                  
        thrust &[N]              & 5000     & 5000      &10000          & 5000        &10000\\
        altitude &[km]           & 15       & 10        &15             & 15          &15   \\
        n2(k): $x_f-x_0$ &       & 24.8671 & 25.0002    &14.0379        & 24.8678    &14.0379 13.9663 13.8099\\
        n1(k): $x_f-x_0$ &       & 24.8671 & 25.0002    &14.0379        & 24.8678    &/\\
        n1(k-2): $x_f-x_0$ - 30&       & 26.8671 & 27.0002    &16.0379        & 26.8678    &/\\
        n1(k-4): $x_f-x_0$ - 60 &      & 28.8671 & 29.0002  & /               & 28.8678    &/\\ % [1ex] adds vertical space
        n1(k+1.5): $x_f-x_0$ + 22.5 &     & /        & /         &12.5379        & /           &/\\
        diversion j &        & /        & /         & /              & $\pm$1.5    &$\pm$1.5/3/4.5\\
        \hline %inserts single line
        \end{tabular}
        \label{table:testcases} % is used to refer this table in the text
        \end{table}

\end{document}
```

I would like to align horizontally the expressions placed on the first column, from 4th to 8th rows. In particular, I would like to get all the `x_f-x_0` aligned. How could I do it?

Comment: Does one of the following two versions suit your needs?  https://i.stack.imgur.com/znYfu.png

Comment: The first one @leandriis. Thank you! EDIT: or maybe also the second one with the first three rows and last one (always first column) also centered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are three different versions using two columns for expressions such as `n2(k): $x_f-x_0$`. I also included a version, that fits into the textwidth without allowing the table to protrude into the left and right margin, while also using `booktabs`-style horizontal and no vertical lines:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}   

 \begin{table}[htbp]
        \caption{Test Cases} % title of Table
        \centering % used for centering table
        \addtolength{\leftskip} {-2cm}
        \addtolength{\rightskip}{-2cm}
        \begin{tabular}{l@{\;}l l c c c | c >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.5cm}} % columns type and number    
        \hline\hline %inserts double horizontal lines
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{Parameters}& &NoCross\#1 & NoCross\#2 & NoCross\#3 & Cross\#1 & Cross\#2 \\ [0.5ex] % inserts table
        %heading
        \hline % inserts single horizontal line
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{mass} &[kg]               & 1500     & 1500      &1500           & 1500        &1500\\ % inserting body of the table                                  
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{thrust} &[N]              & 5000     & 5000      &10000          & 5000        &10000\\
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{altitude} &[km]           & 15       & 10        &15             & 15          &15   \\
        n2(k):& $x_f-x_0$ &       & 24.8671 & 25.0002    &14.0379        & 24.8678    &14.0379 13.9663 13.8099\\
        n1(k):& $x_f-x_0$ &       & 24.8671 & 25.0002    &14.0379        & 24.8678    &/\\
        n1(k-2):& $x_f-x_0 - 30$&       & 26.8671 & 27.0002    &16.0379        & 26.8678    &/\\
        n1(k-4):& $x_f-x_0 - 60$ &      & 28.8671 & 29.0002  & /               & 28.8678    &/\\ % [1ex] adds vertical space
        n1(k+1.5):& $x_f-x_0 + 22.5$ &     & /        & /         &12.5379        & /           &/\\
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{diversion j} &        & /        & /         & /              & $\pm$1.5    &$\pm$1.5/3/4.5\\
        \hline %inserts single line
        \end{tabular}
        \label{table:testcases} % is used to refer this table in the text
        \end{table}
        
 \begin{table}[htbp]
        \caption{Test Cases} % title of Table
        \centering % used for centering table
        \addtolength{\leftskip} {-2cm}
        \addtolength{\rightskip}{-2cm}
        \begin{tabular}{r@{\;}l l c c c | c >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.5cm}} % columns type and number    
        \hline\hline %inserts double horizontal lines
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{Parameters}& &NoCross\#1 & NoCross\#2 & NoCross\#3 & Cross\#1 & Cross\#2 \\ [0.5ex] % inserts table
        %heading
        \hline % inserts single horizontal line
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{mass} &[kg]               & 1500     & 1500      &1500           & 1500        &1500\\ % inserting body of the table                                  
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{thrust} &[N]              & 5000     & 5000      &10000          & 5000        &10000\\
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{altitude} &[km]           & 15       & 10        &15             & 15          &15   \\
        n2(k):& $x_f-x_0$ &       & 24.8671 & 25.0002    &14.0379        & 24.8678    &14.0379 13.9663 13.8099\\
        n1(k):& $x_f-x_0$ &       & 24.8671 & 25.0002    &14.0379        & 24.8678    &/\\
        n1(k-2):& $x_f-x_0 - 30$&       & 26.8671 & 27.0002    &16.0379        & 26.8678    &/\\
        n1(k-4):& $x_f-x_0 - 60$ &      & 28.8671 & 29.0002  & /               & 28.8678    &/\\ % [1ex] adds vertical space
        n1(k+1.5):& $x_f-x_0 + 22.5$ &     & /        & /         &12.5379        & /           &/\\
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{diversion j} &        & /        & /         & /              & $\pm$1.5    &$\pm$1.5/3/4.5\\
        \hline %inserts single line
        \end{tabular}
        \label{table:testcases} % is used to refer this table in the text
        \end{table}

 \begin{table}[htbp]
        \caption{Test Cases} % title of Table
        \centering
        \setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
        \begin{tabular}{l@{\;}l c c c  c c}   
        \toprule
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{Parameters}    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{NoCross} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Cross} \\
        \cmidrule(r){3-5} \cmidrule(l){6-7} 
                                        & & \#1        & \#2        & \#3        & \#1      & \#2          \\ 
        \midrule 
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{mass [kg]}     & 1500       & 1500       & 1500       & 1500     & 1500          \\
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{thrust [N]}    & 5000       & 5000       & 10000      & 5000     & 10000         \\
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{altitude [km]} & 15         & 10         & 15         & 15       & 15            \\
        n2(k):& $x_f-x_0$                 & 24.8671    & 25.0002    & 14.0379    & 24.8678  & \makecell[t]{14.0379\\ 13.9663\\ 13.8099}\\
        n1(k):& $x_f-x_0$                 & 24.8671    & 25.0002    & 14.0379    & 24.8678  &               \\
        n1(k-2):& $x_f-x_0 - 30$          & 26.8671    & 27.0002    & 16.0379    & 26.8678  &               \\
        n1(k-4):& $x_f-x_0 - 60$          & 28.8671    & 29.0002    &            & 28.8678  &               \\
        n1(k+1.5):& $x_f-x_0 + 22.5$      &            &            & 12.5379    &          &               \\
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{diversion j}   &            &            &            & $\pm$1.5 & $\pm$1.5/3/4.5\\
        \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \label{table:testcases}
        \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @leandriis, just one last question: is there a professional way to point out that [km] unit of measure is also extendend for all the rows from the third one to the last one (considering the second column)? Or the only way is just to repeat the information throughout the table?